# testing hypothesis in spatial sure models

Tags: spatial, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I have estimated spatial sur models (lag and error) using the spse program, spseml function. I want to test some restrictions about the coefficients in this model and I have not been able to do it using LinearHypothesis. How should I do it?

Thanks in advance,

Dr. Pilar González
University of the Basque Country

Comment: If you can expand your question and provide some codes, it would be very useful